# AWS Lambda, delay before handler is called

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am having a problem with AWS Lambda.

```
console.log('a')
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  console.log('b')
```

I have console.logs placed here. In the CloudWatch console, I notice `a` gets printed a full five seconds before `b` is. What is causing this time difference? Is it the cold start because as far as I know it certainly shouldn't take this long.

I am using NodeJS by the way. Packages: `firebase-admin`, `ytsr`, `node-fetch`. Updating available memory makes the speed faster.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You'll find this interesting: [Operating Lambda: Performance optimization – Part 1 | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-1/)

Comment: Are you sure that this is your real code? There is no reason for the delay to be 5 seconds.

Comment: @Marcin the delay is sometimes 10+ seconds. My npm packages are firebase-admin, node-fetch, and ytsr. I've always thought the cold start would be shorter.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein That article was very interesting. I followed some steps and added a bit more memory to the function and it does speed it up a bit. I'd like to see if there are some other ways since afaik cold starts shouldn't be this long even with minimal compute power.

Comment: How many packages do you load? What do they do to get initialized? Please update your question with exact description of your setup, because clearly the 3 lines you posted is not your real code.

Comment: @Marcin for reference, I posted the code to show where I placed the console.logs with the simple question of what is happening in between. John's comment was helpful as it pointed me to the answer that it's a cold start. Updated the question with some more details as well.